# Java - Illegal use of reserved word 'import'

Tags: java, import, package, adobe, extendscript

I'm trying to import the package java.util.regex.*; and keep hitting an error in line 1 of my code.

```
import  java.util.regex.*;
```

Returns error: Illegal use of reserved word 'import'

Any idea what is going on here?

I'm writing my code in Adobe ExtendScript Toolkit for use in Photoshop CC.

Comment: Ends with a semi colon;

Comment: Is ExtendScript Java?

Comment: Yes I forgot to include semicolon here.  Semicolon is present in the actual code.

Comment: Note that JavaScript (ExtendScript seems to be JavaScript-like) and Java are entirely different languages.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExtendScript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ExtendScript is not Java. Java syntax does not work in ExtendScript.

Java standard classes are also not available from ExtendScript.